# How to use localeRoute from nuxt-i18n package in vuex

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I am trying to use localRoute method from [nuxt-i18n](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/setup)

`this.$router.push(this.localeRoute({ name: "home" }))`

I tried this way but it's not working, what is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors/exceptions?

Comment: localeRoute of undefined

Answer (score 1):

inside vuex, this.localRoute or this.localPath is undefined because "this" is out of context.

What does work, is passing the whole,localPath object into the action.

So in your method you do this:

```
test(){
      let route = this.localePath({ name: 'forgotPassword' })
      this.$store.dispatch('storeTest', route)
    },
```

then inside the action you can do:

```
  storeTest({ commit }, route){

     this.app.router.push(route) //this works
     $nuxt._router.push(route) //this works as well
  },
```

In the same way, you could pass the whole router into the action if the other options do not work. Then you can do: `router.push(route)`